# C++ MySQL connector: How to use or simulate mysql_ping()

Tags: c++, mysql

I´m using MySql C++ Connector driver, and it seens not to have the `mysql_ping()` function (at least from [this official link here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=65640)

As for the given link, something like the above code would work:

```
if (connection->isClosed())
    connection->reconnect();
```

The problem is that `reconnect` also does not exist. My code does not compile with this error:

`class sql::Connection has no member named ‘reconnect’`

PS: The driver class `SqlDriver*` does not have reconnect also.

How can I call or simulate a `mysql_ping()` using the C++ connector ?

Comment: What is the version of Connector/C++ are you using?

Comment: Have you tried automatic [reconnection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/auto-reconnect.html)?